# Kill activity when it comes to foreground

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

i m writing an application n stuckup with one problem.I have three activity A,B and C. when i goes from activty A to B and B to C and if i press menu button on device.my application goes into background state. when i reopen application it shows Activity C. I want when i reopen my application it should shows Activity A instead of any other activity from Activity stack.
I have gone through some activity lifecycle method and try to override it.i have override onStart() ,onPause() method and finsh activity C as well as Activity B and the problem i m facing is when i go from Activity C to activity D activity C finish all background activity n m not able to go back to acitvity C on finish of Activity D.
Can anyone help me how to show specific acitivity on resume of application??
thansks in advance.

here is my manifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<application    
              android:icon="@drawable/icon"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >

    <activity   
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="com.buttonpay.Login"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


     <activity android:name=".ButtonPayActivity"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>    


    <!-- HomeTab Activity -->

            <activity android:name="com.buttonpay.home.Utilities"
                        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>


            <activity android:name="com.buttonpay.home.Top_up"
                        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
            <activity android:name="com.buttonpay.home.HomeScreen"
                        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

            <activity android:name="com.buttonpay.home.MyAccount"
                        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
             <activity android:name="com.buttonpay.home.TransactionHistory"
                        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
              <activity android:name="com.buttonpay.home.TransactionDetailsActivity"
                        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
                <activity android:name="com.buttonpay.home.TransactionList"
                        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
               <activity android:name="com.buttonpay.home.BusinessSummaryActivity"
                        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
               <activity android:name=".home.MobileMoneyActivity"
                        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>


     <!-- balance tab Activity -->
            <activity android:name="com.buttonpay.balance.BalanceTab"
                        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                        />



     <!-- Favouritetab Activity -->
             <activity android:name="com.buttonpay.favourite.FavouriteTab"
                        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                        />

  <!-- ComingSoon -->
<activity android:name="com.buttonpay.home.ComingSoon"
                        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

 <!-- Settings -->
<activity android:name="com.buttonpay.settings.SettingList"
                        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>



</application>
```

Comment: the solution of David below worked for you ?

Comment: no david's solution is not working..
i have login activity,menu activity ane discription activity when i press menubutton on device,app goes minimize and when i reopen app it shows description activity.i want login activity should be displyed..
any help??

Comment: i have added manifest.xml in question.take a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the manifest, set this on your **root activity** (that is the first one that gets launched in your application, the one with ACTION_MAIN and CATEGORY_LAUNCHER):

```
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```

You don't need to do anything else. No overriding of lifecycle methods.

**EDIT Add additional information after some empirical experimentation:**

You need to make sure that your **root activity** is always in the task's activity stack to make this work. This means that you can't call `finish()` on the **root activity** until the user actually wants to quit your application (ie: when he presses the BACK key when in your **root activity**).

In your example you have a LoginActivity, MenuActivity and DescriptionActivity and the LoginActivity is the **root activity**. When the LoginActivity launches the MenuActivity it cannot call `finish()` on itself. In this case, when the user presses the BACK key while in the MenuActivity, it will return to the LoginActivity. If this isn't what you want then you need to set a flag in the LoginActivity that you've already launched the MenuActivity and when `onResume()` is called you can check that flag to determine if you are returning from the MenuActivity and in that case you can just immediately call `finish()`.

Comment: not working..
i have login activity,menu activity ane discription activity when i press menubutton on device,app goes minimize and when i reopen app it shows description activity.i want login activity should be displyed..
any help??

Comment: Yes, I'm looking at it. Please don't pester me to help you, that isn't nice. I'm not getting paid for this, I'm doing it out of the goodness of my heart. StackOverflow isn't where you go if you want to pester people to help you. Have a bit of patience...

Comment: How are you starting the program when you put it on the device? From the installed/web-browser? Or via your IDE (IntelliJ, Eclipse)? Or are you opening the list of available applications on the phone and starting it there?

Comment: i have a list of application on my phone and starting from that and also running app on simulator too...

Comment: I've created a small test program with 3 activities: A, B and C. I've set `android:clearTaskOnLaunch' for ActivityA. I started the app. ActivityA starts ActivityB which starts ActivityC. All 3 activities are in the activity stack. I press the HOME button. App goes to background. I start the app again. I see ActivityA.

Comment: I think I understand the problem now. You have already called `finish()` in your login activity, right? You need to make sure that your **root** activity stays in the task as the first activity. You can't call finish() on it until you want to end your application.

Comment: yup...that was the problem....thanks 4 help...problem has been solved...thanks a lot man...

Comment: I added some additional comments to my answer. Glad to be of help. Next time try to have a bit more patience, you'll get more help that way.

Comment: One of the great answer...+1 to both of you...:)